# How can I install nmslib on Windows 10

Tags: pip

I am trying to install scispacy with pip and found that the installatio of nmslib was causing issues. There are various posts on the internet as to how to fix this, but none seem to be working for me.

I am running Python 3.7.4 on a Windows 10 laptop
Pip is version 19.2.1

Here is error part of the logs

```
2019-08-08T18:25:20,901 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y6n2f026\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y6n2f026\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-90f_5c93\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902 Exception information:
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902 Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902   File "c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902     status = self.run(options, args)
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902   File "c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 407, in run
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902     use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902   File "c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902     **kwargs
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902   File "c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 959, in install
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902     spinner=spinner,
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902   File "c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 934, in call_subprocess
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902     raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
2019-08-08T18:25:20,902 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y6n2f026\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y6n2f026\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-90f_5c93\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

A few weeks ago I had the same issue and amongst the million things I tried I was able to get it to work, but at the time I wasn't entirely sure how I did it. I'm now on a new computer and the issue won't go away.

Comment: I don't think that's the important part of the error: that's just showing pip failing, not why it failed. I assume exc_msg has more detail, and it printed it too? But I'd guess this is down to trying to compile something itself rather than finding and installing a binary package that's failing?

Comment: Please post the complete error trace. The part in question is a generic message that is displayed on every error.

Comment: That's the entirety of the actual error component. For the full log, see https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib/files/3480622/err.txt

Comment: The actual compiler errors are: "error C3861: '_mm_prefetch': identifier not found" and "error C2065: '_MM_HINT_T0': undeclared identifier". Which means you're missing xmmintrin.h (or some other -intrin.h), or the nmslib code knows you don't have / don't support this but is erroneously trying to use it anyway. So it's a compile error in nmslib that you might be able to fix in your environment: see if you work out why it is or isn't including this, and whether the lines in pivot_neighb_invindx.cc can do without it.

Comment: ... but you already know that, because you posted on this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib/issues/399 . Did you try the fix suggested there, change mmintrin.h to xmmintrin.h ? Did it work?

Comment: I have tried the fix there, with a similar error message

Answer (score 4):

`nmslib` is a python wrapper over a `c++` library. Therefore it could cause problems on few systems. I had the same issue.

Please clone the repository from [here](https://github.com/allenai/scispacy) and install manually instead of the `pip` installation.

**Try one of the following.**

1. As per the comments from [here](https://github.com/allenai/scispacy/issues/137),`nmslib` is optional and is only required if you use it for linker.So you may comment it from the requirements.txt and then do a manual installation via `setup.py`

   **Or**
2. In your `requirements.txt file` add `numpy` to the top and install via `setup.py` file.

Though the above steps may throw a VC++ error, the `scispacy` module will get installed and you will be able to import it.

I tried both the solutions and they worked for me.

**Note :** Also, from the comments I understand that, now we may directly use `spacy` and load the `scispacy` models provided you have downloaded and installed the models.

```
pip install en_core_sci_sm
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_sm")
```

Let me know which one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that are trying a new version of Python, the 3.8.2 worked for me.
I found it on this thread: https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib/issues/529.

You also have to install the Visual C++ Build Tools : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

With these dependencies:
[image]

I spent 2 days on it haha.